# ProtractorJS_Selenium Server_при запуске браузера все элементы страницы редиректят на начальную страницу

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Добрый день!

Я еще зеленый в автоматизации. Но стремительно стараюсь посинеть.
Проблема такова:
Ресурс написан с использование фреймворка AngularJS. Все ссылки содержали "#" - https://test.com.ua/#/ до вчерашнего дня. Все тесты писались с использование ProtractorJS. Вчера же FE разработчики убрали из url этот знак, позже выяснил что они перевели AngularJS  в режим HTML5.

Все тесты начали падать: Protractor открывает браузер, заходит на тестируемый сайт, кликает на нужный элемент и ждет его появления. НО! На сайте ничего не происходит. Я пробовал ставить режим ожидания на дольше и руками прощелкивать в открытом тестом браузере - все элементы страницы (ссылки, кнопки, разделы) редиректят на начальную страницу, просто обновляется виджет страницы. Видны изменения только в теге, отвечающий за название вкладки браузера.

В чем может быть причина? Помогите, пожалуйста. А то это напоминает игру на выживание.
Если просто самому открыть браузер - все работает корректно.

Webdriver-manager 12.0.6, 
Protractor 5.1.1, 
Jasmine 2.6.0, 
NodeJS 7.8.0, 
Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Answer (score -1):

Благодаря помощи xotabu4'а с http://automated-testing.info и подрядчика по FE, решили проблему. Если кому интересно. Для метода `browser.get()` я использовал ссылку с встроенной первичной авторизацией. Оказалось что html5 режим использует js функцию `history.pushState`. Но в браузерах есть правило запрета подмены домена(можно менять только в рамках того же окружения), и браузер в URL убирает пару логин-пароль. Но в переменной domain сохраняет путь [https://логин:пароль@test.com](https://%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD:%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C@test.com). И получается, что https://test.com/about для него является другим доменом - они не совпадают.

Решение:

```
browser.get('https://логин:пароль@test.com/') //осуществляется запись в текущую сессию данных первичной авторизации
browser.get('https://test.com/');
```